# TCP or UDP for Stop & Wait / Go Back N

Tags: tcp, udp, transport-protocol

I'm creating server/client classes for "Stop & Wait" and "Go Back N" (variant of sliding window) protocols, though I'm unsure on whether I should pursue TCP or UDP. From my current understanding I would implement UDP in "Stop & Wait" whilst TCP in "Go Back N"?

Furthermore would I implement aspects of TCP within my "Stop & Wait"? As I understand "Go Back N" is simply an extension of "Stop & Wait", just without the waiting.

Sorry if the answers are obvious, trying to wrap my head around these protocols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TCP is essentially a refined version of Stop and Wait plus Go back N.  If you want to build your own, use UDP.

Comment: Could I ask why you would use UDP, surely if TCP is a refined version you could simply expand it to Stop and Wait / Go Back N? And even more so if they ARE almost mirrors of TCP then why not use TCP?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your original question. Are you trying to write your own version of Stop and Wait?

Comment: Yes, creating both server and client (receiver and client) classes for Stop and Wait and then use that to then create Go Back N.

Comment: TCP will give you a reliable stream of data, so there's no point to implementing S&W.  You won't have any "reason" to stop or go back, because you will never get packet loss.